# TFS build не подставляет значение макроса $(VSInstallDir)

Tags: msbuild, tfs

Есть довольно интересная проблемка, которую ну никак не получается решить. Имеем build-машину где собираются билды. Недавно внес изменения для запуска утилиты *editbin.exe* с параметром *LARGEADDRESSAWARE* в конце каждого билда, которая расположена в папке *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin* (понятно, что путь к папке может меняться). В build прожекте добавил новый target:

```
<Exec command="&quot;$(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin\editbin.exe&quot; /LARGEADDRESSAWARE &quot;Manager.exe&quot;"/>
```

Если запустить MSBuild локально с этим таргетом на этой же машине, то все работает. Гуд! Но при чекине и при попытке собраться билд падает с такой ошибкой:
**The command ""\VC\bin\editbin.exe"" exited with code 3.**
Как видно, TFS build не подставил значение $(VSInstallDir) макроса. Как лечить?

UPD: 
Я выяснил, что на билд машине есть вот такой замечательный файлик: **C:/Program Files/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/TeamBuild/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets**
В нем есть определение

```
<VSINSTALLDIR Condition="'$(VSINSTALLDIR)'=='' and '$(NetSamplePath)'!=''">$(NetSamplePath)\..\..<VSINSTALLDIR>
```

Так вот как я понимаю $(NetSamplePath) почему-то пустой. Но Google почти ничего не знает про этот макрос.

Comment: все логично, у вас на сервере TFS за сборку отвечает совсем не VS

Comment: Нет, не логично. Для TFS билда так же есть определение VSInstallDir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом:
Process->Build process parameters->5. Advances->MSBuild arguments

/p:VSInstallDir=Значение

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `VSInstallDir` определяется в файле `Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props`, который автоматически подключается ко всем проектам c++.

Находится этот файл по пути `$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props`, где `VCTargetsPath` - это предопределенная переменная. Но лучше включать не его, а сначала `$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`, после чего файл `$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props` - поскольку именно так поступает сама студия, есть гарантия обратной совместимости подобного решения.